# How to dispaly small images in select element (form API) in drupal 7

Tags: image, forms, api, drupal-7

I'd like to know how I can display images in select element in Drupal form API.

The following code shows simple select with two options which are in text format: "-34-", "-36-".

```
    $sizes = array_combine(array(34, 36), array("-34-", "-36-")); 
    $form['editplayer']['clothes_size_female']['clothes'] = array( 
        '#type' => 'select', 
        '#default_value' => 34, 
        '#options' => $sizes,  
    );
```

I tried to place path to images but it considers it as a string. `$sizes = array_combine(array(34, 36), array("http://localhost/drupal/renderImage.php?user_id=34", "http://localhost/drupal/renderImage.php?user_id=36"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a well-supported way to do this using stock HTML select box elements. There are solutions to do it with JavaScript though:

http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/28/reinventing-drop-down-with-css-jquery.aspx

You'd have to write a custom Drupal form element though to have it work with the Form API.

Comment: Where can i read about how to write my own  form element for drupal7? A already know one article, but when i try to do what was written there i got nothing(no errors, no output) http://www.akchauhan.com/create-drupal-form-elements-like-date-element/

Comment: I just skimmed it but that tutorial is for an older version of Drupal. For one, they've changed hook_elements to hook_element_info() in Drupal 7. Read the info at this link - http://drupal.org/node/966550 Also don't forget to flush the cache when making changes to hook_theme and hook_element_info as this stuff gets cached.